# libtidy .NET wrapper html5

Tags: c#, html, htmltidy

Is there anything as an HTML5 libtidy .NET wrapper ?
I have been looking around and all I can find is [Mark Beaton's Tidy Managed](https://github.com/markbeaton/TidyManaged).

It doesn't seem to support HTML5 gracefully. I have been using it in the past with great success, but it's no longer a good fit.

Then there is this [HTML Tidy with HTML5 support](https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5).

But I was hoping there is a .NET wrapper for it (than I can't seem to find, no matter what).

Also it needs to build on x64 so I understand the chances are close to zero :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the NewInlineTags property. Works for me:

```
var td = Document.FromFile(InFileName);
// new HTML5 tags
td.NewInlineTags = "section, aside, header, nav, footer";
```

Comment: Your new tags are block level tags not inline tags. [See Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements). So I guess they should go into the `NewBlockLevelTags` instead.